# Separate TCP/SSL connection for authentication while UDP for main traffic?

Tags: java, android, tcp, udp

I am currently writing a on a small client/server software, where the server runs on PC/Mac (Java) and the client on Android. The client is sending many small packets to the server, where low latency is important and single packet drops dont matter, which is why I want to use UDP for that.

The problem is that I want some authentication, since the server should only accept packets from a known device (a third party should not be able to send valid packets, however it doesnt matter if it can read such packets).

So what I was thinking about is, that the authentication could happen on a separate TCP (or even SSL) connection, while the main traffic happens over UDP. Only UDP packets from the same IP address as the TCP/SSL connection are accepted, and only as long as the connection is alive.

Is this a (relatively) safe authentication method or are there easy ways to bypass that? If so, do you have any other suggestions for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses can be forged. So anyone sniffing the packages, can send bogus UDP packages as well.

You could exchange a secret key over your SSL connection and add a [`HMAC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to your UDP package.